# studying for exam ; just how to start

Tags: linux, shell-script

Take two command line parameters, the first of which is the name of a directory, and the second is a file size in bytes. Call your shell script “listfiles”.
 The call from the shell prompt should look like “$ listfiles /tmp 50”.
 First of all, your shell script should check that only two parameters are passed to it.
 Then your shell script should check that the first parameter is in fact a directory.
 Your shell script, should list all the regular files in the directory to which you have read access and that are smaller than the given size.

Answer (score 6):

As this is a homework I will only give hints:

1. Arguments passed to the script will be available as `$1` and `$2` (etc. for more arguments).
2. `$#` will be the number of arguments passed.
3. The `[ -d "dir" ]` test will test whether `dir` is a directory.
4. `find . -type f -size -50` will find all regular files in the *current* directory (`.`) with size less than 50 bytes.

A simple first start:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "There are $# arguments passed, the first two are '$1' and '$2'"
```

You should be able to read up on the rest by either reading relevant questions and answers on this site, or by using the `man` command to read the manual of the shell you are using (e.g. `man bash`). In `bash` you may also use the command `help test` to read about the `-d` test and how to compare numbers.

`find` is documented in `man find` and extensively referenced in questions on this site.

You should also consult whatever learning materials are associated with the class you are taking.

This question will likely be closed as a duplicate of your question from previous. If you have further questions, please make them *specific and about particular issues you are facing while solving your problem*.

A good question contains an explanation of the issue, the code that you are using, the way that you are executing your code, any actual error messages and/or warning messages that you see, along with what you expected the code would do.  See also ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help).

We are happy to help you, but we will not write your script for you.